# Configuring IIS 7 & ASP.NET App for URL Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, url-routing

This is not an MVC topic.
I have an ASP.NET Application which performs URL Routing in the `Application_Start` method.

The routing looks like:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route(
  "Profile/{query}",
  new RouteValueDictionary() { {"query",string.Empty} },
  new GenericRouteHandler("~/ProfileHttpHandler.ashx")
));
```

A `GenericRouteHandler` looks implements `GetHttpHandler` with:

```
var page= (IHttpHandler)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath, typeof(IHttpHandler));
...
return page;
```

And ProfileHttpHandler.ashx is just a Visual Studio template.  It sets Content-type to "text/plain" and writes "hello world."

This application works correctly while debugging in Visual Studio (on the ASP.NET development server). A `GET http://localhost:59474/Profile/abc123` routes to the http handler as expected.

However, when this app is published to a remote machine running IIS 7 in Integrated Pipeline mode, the process fails.  I get HTTP 500 errors when attempting to GET anything inside the apps folder, including Default.aspx.

Web.Config is configured as such:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="RoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="RoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Lastly; I'm unsure whether this is relevant information.  In my web service provider's control panel, I have the directory which this application resides in configured as a virtual directory.
It has the properties:

- mydomain.ca/routeapp: Folder in your Hosting Space (domain.ca\wwwroot\routeapp)
- Allow Anonymous Access: On.
- Enable Integrated Windows Authentication: On.
- Enable Basic Authentication: On.
- ASP: Disabled.
- ASP.NET: 2.0 Integrated Pipeline.
- PHP: Disabled.
- Perl: Enabled.

Comment: Can you find out what the 500 error is, from the event log on the server?

Comment: I'm working with my provider to try to get some logs.  The most recent log file on the file system is locked and I can't seem to access it.
I have verified that the 500 error is in direct response to the application described in the OP. Publishing a fresh Web Application to the virtual dir gets me HTTP 200s.

Comment: Hi again.  Unfortunately, the logfiles don't include enough information to be useful.

Comment: Can you try to switch to Classic Pipeline mode just to see if it works?

Comment: It doesn't work in Classic Mode either.  I changed it to Integrated in direct response to the errors I'm having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add this to your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

For more information on this check the [iis forum thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150266.aspx).

Comment: I didn't include that in my OP because I didn't know it was relevant.  Yet, it is already included in my web.config file.

Comment: It seems I'm not destined to get routing working with WebForms.  I've ported my project over to MVC and am having much less trouble.  In the name of closing this thread, I'm assigning this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

To configure an ASP.NET Web site or Web application for routing, you first need to add a reference to the System.Web.Routing assembly.The SP1 installation for the .NET Framework 3.5 will install this assembly into the global assembly cache, and you can find the assembly inside the standard "Add Reference" dialog box.

Check [this link](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/9992a0bc-90f5-4f04-823a-31f901b61643/?URL+Routing+in+ASP.Net+3.5%28IIS7%29)